# Sharing Certificate with 3rd Party Developer

Tags: ios, mobile, itunes-store

We have had a number of apps built by a 3rd party developer. I cannot remember how this was done in the past, but they have just updated 2 of our apps to work correctly with iOS 5.x

The agreement is that they will build and sign the files ready for us to upload to iTunes. We cannot build the code as the agreement doesn't include the source.

I have sent them the Distribution Provisioning Profile (.mobileprovision) but they have asked for the "Certificate for Keychain access"

Perhaps I am being overly cautious, but am I right in thinking I need to export my Developer Certificate as a .cer file and email that to them? We do trust the company, but is this the correct way to do things? Is it allowed by Apple?

The 3rd party have no access to our accounts (developer centre / iTunes connect) and we have no access to the source code.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're going to build things as you, they'll need your certificate and private key as well as the provisioning profile. I don't think there's any way round that if they're going to do the building and code-signing.

I think it's a fairly typical way to do things, in a situation where the client has the dev account but the developer owns the source.

Even if the development company did have access to your iTunes account, you'd still need to send them the private key that your certificate was created with.

Comment: Just to clarify, you say I need to send them the certificate (for my developer) and my private key - but in the last sentence you say that I'd "still need to send them the private key" - this is the same key?

Comment: Yep. Each certificate is created with a private key (you can create the private key at the same time as creating the certificate if you want), and you need that private key on the machine you do the code signing on.

Comment: Thanks. Just so that I am 100% clear on what to export and send them, I am clicking on 'login' keychains, then from My Certificates / Keys I export iPhone Developer: AlexHolsgrove (as a .cer file) and the accompanying private key with my name (as a .p12 file with a password) I then send the developer both files? Sorry if I'm repeating myself, but I've seen many other people confused by this!

Comment: I think so. I can see why you're confused — each time I have to do this, it takes me a bit of time to remember! I believe that's correct. They'll also need the provisioning profile of course.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried it myself, but seems like there is a way to re-sign the binary (IPA file). Check [this link](http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/) It uses a utility called [iReSign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign)